# Best way to dynamically load an xml configuration file into a Flex4/Flash movie at runtime?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-cs4

I've got a rather simple question about loading in an xml file at runtime in a SWF.

I've found a couple different methods to load in the xml.

- myXml.load("file.xml");
- HTTPService object
- URLStream object

What is better way to load an xml file that always has the same name and is located in the same folder as the SWF on the web server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) - I think that's the most lightweight one.

- The complexity of `URLStream` is unnecessary as far as a configuration file is concerned.
- `HTTPService` again is heavy for this simple task (and Flex only). Of course, it allows you to get away with minimum code, but I use it only for something that needs to be updated repeatedly (binding the `lastResult` to a live `DataGrid` etc).
- `myXml.load()` - this is not AS3, is it?

Comment: Thanks Amarghosh - and you're correct myXml.load() is AS2 and earlier